# Unity Tcpclient connect to python socket server only in local but not in AWS(python server)

Tags: python, c#, unity-game-engine, sockets, amazon-ec2

i have python server code like below.

```
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
serverPort = 5000
serverSocket.bind(('aws ec2 private ip', serverPort))
serverSocket.listen(1)
print('server listening')

clientSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
print('Connection from ', addr[0])

...
```

and i also have c# client code like below.

```
    public void ConnectToServer()
    {
        try
        {
            clientSocket = new TcpClient();
            clientSocket.Connect("aws ec2 public ip", 5000);
            stream = clientSocket.GetStream();
            Debug.Log("server connected");
        }
        
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            Debug.LogError(e);
        }
    }

...
```

these codes work in local env.
but when i upload python server code on AWS ec2, unity script(in my computer) doesn't work.

it shows error

system.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): Connection refused
at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.Connect (System.String hostname, System.Int32 port) [0x0019d] in <2fe115660d9c47728edff248f3625297>:0
at SocketClient.ConnectToServer () [0x0000b] in ...

So, i test python client code like below.

```
from socket import *

Host = 'aws ec2 public ip'
Port = 5000

clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
clientSocket.connect((Host, Port))

...
```

And it works... server print 'Connection from "my ip"'
Therefore it's not problem of firewall nor setting on AWS.

What's problem in my unity code...

server(ec2) python version is 3.7.10

unity version is 2021.3.9f1, 2021.3.11f1(i tested both version)
OS Mac Monterey 12.6

Answer (score 0):

What is it doing with a “aws ec2 public ip” as a host? That doesn’t look like a domain. It is possible that python works differently and you think that c# tcpclients can figure out what that means, but I don’t think they can. I could be completely wrong, but I would be surprised if you could host a server on a domain with spaces that you almost certainly don’t own.

Comment: That is an example. The actual input is in the same format as "15.164.xx.xxx" and Python server has code written in the same format as serverSocket.bind('', 5000).

Comment: @김태윤 My bad for misunderstanding, I feel silly now. I don’t know what your problem could be in that case.